# How to give a default value to an std::array with Visual C++ 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, stdarray

How to give a default value to an std::array? For example, something like

```
void f(std::array<int, 3> pt = std::array<int, 3>{0, 1, 2});
```

After checking with helpful comments. I think it is due to the compiler. How to work it around with VS 2012 without creating a function like `std::array<int, 3> MakeArray(...)` ?

Comment: Did you try it? Hint: it works.

Comment: Just like that. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Did you ask your compiler? Because I asked mine and he was fine with it.

Comment: I am using vs2012. It gives compilation errors.

Comment: And those errors are?

Comment: 17 errors. "{" error; ";" error and son on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
void f(std::array<int, 3> pt = {0, 1, 2});
```

Or I would write simply

```
void f(std::array<int, 3> = {0, 1, 2});
```

In GCC this code is not compiled. It seems it is a bug of the compiler. However you can write for GCC either as

```
void f( std::array<int, 3> = std::array<int, 3>( { 1, 2, 3 } ) );
```

or

```
void f( std::array<int, 3> = { { 1, 2, 3 } } );
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with GCC 4.8 (calling `f()` gives an error: `array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`). OP's version does work.

Comment: @interjay, It works as is on Clang, but GCC wants double braces.